# MySQL select overlapping count

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to combine these four queries into one:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM conversations WHERE DAY(create_time)=DAY(NOW());
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM conversations WHERE WEEKOFYEAR(create_time)=WEEKOFYEAR(NOW());
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM conversations WHERE MONTH(create_time)=MONTH(NOW());
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM conversations WHERE YEAR(create_time)=YEAR(NOW());
```

This single query would return to me, for example

day => # of conversations from today,

week => # of conversations from this week,

month => # of conversations from this month,

year => # of conversations from this year

I thought I was about there with some CASE syntax (I'm no MySQL expert), but realized each record seemed to only be able to be counted in one case, and I need them to overlap.  In other words, I could have a single record counted for one of these cases, two, three, or all four.

Comment: Bear in mind that `DAY(create_time) = DAY(NOW())` will not match, as you write, conversations from today, but rather will match conversations created on a day of any month matching that of today's date.  If today is the 5th of whatever, that WHERE clause will match conversations created on the 5th of any month of any year in your table.  A similar remark applies to WEEKOFYEAR, MONTH, and YEAR.

Comment: That's great info.  Are there MySQL functions that I should use instead, or should I add qualifying && clauses?

Comment: Tim, at the risk of rep-less answering a question in comments, do `DATE(ct) = CURRENT_DATE`, `YEAR(ct) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)` and add qualifying ANDs for the others.  *Note that this will not use an index on `create_time`*.  More efficient but more arduous is to compute the upper and lower bounds for the current day, week, month, whatever and select `WHERE create_time BETWEEN *lower* AND *upper*`.

Comment: I appreciate the help pilcrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select
    sum(case when DAY(create_time)=DAY(NOW()) then 1 else 0 end) as DayCount,
    sum(case when WEEKOFYEAR(create_time)=WEEKOFYEAR(NOW()) then 1 else 0 end) as WeekCount,
    sum(case when MONTH(create_time)=MONTH(NOW()) then 1 else 0 end) as MonthCount,
    sum(case when YEAR(create_time)=YEAR(NOW()) then 1 else 0 end) as YearCount
from
    conversations
where
    YEAR(create_time)=YEAR(NOW())
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e62f0/1

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the documentation for [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html).
Example usage:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM conversations WHERE DAY(create_time)=DAY(NOW());
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM conversations WHERE WEEKOFYEAR(create_time)=WEEKOFYEAR(NOW());
UNION ALL 
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM conversations WHERE MONTH(create_time)=MONTH(NOW());
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM conversations WHERE YEAR(create_time)=YEAR(NOW());
```